# iframe disable on hover effect

Tags: html, css, iframe, hover

i couldnot disable effect of the element within iframe attribute when you hover on it. are there any alternatives to solve the current problem ??

here is my code and raw solution:

```
iframe id="clock1" src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i52azneg/n2253/szw110/szh110/hbw0/hfc000/cf100/hgr0/fav0/fiv0/mqcfff/mql15/mqw4/mqd94/mhcfff/mhl15/mhw4/mhd94/mmv0/hhcbbb/hmcddd/hsceee" frameborder="0" width="110" height="110"></iframe>

   script>

     $("iframe#clock1").contents().find("#hov").hide();

/script>
```

Comment: Why don't try the css LIke #clock #hov:hover {
display:none;
}

Comment: @YagnikDetroja, i already tried this method, but aint work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This hover effect is coming from the original website.
You can solve this using following code.

```
<div title="Your title Here">
    <iframe id="clock1" src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i52azneg/n2253/szw110/szh110/hbw0/hfc000/cf100/hgr0/fav0/fiv0/mqcfff/mql15/mqw4/mqd94/mhcfff/mhl15/mhw4/mhd94/mmv0/hhcbbb/hmcddd/hsceee" frameborder="0" width="110" height="110" style="pointer-events: none;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Anyway I don't recommend this because the message is to give credit for the developer. This is not ethically correct.

Comment: thanks, it blocks all pointer events, i got it, but now how i can only add only title element for this iframe ? like <iframe  title="aaabbb" > ??

Answer (score 1):

Simple CSS does the trick:

```
pointer-events: none
```